# Ocelat api gateway documentation with swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, ocelot

I've developed a project based on microservices(11 microservices) and used `Ocelat` for api gateway but I'm struggling with generate microservice api documentation, `Ocelat` says use this way to generate document by create swagger json file in gateway project and add all api endpoint:

```
app.Map("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", b =>
                {
                    b.Run(x =>
                       File.ReadAllTextAsync(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory,
                               "ApiDocumentation/Swagger.json"))
                           .ContinueWith(readTask => x.Response.WriteAsync(readTask.Result))
                        );
```

but every time that my microservice api was changed I have to edit this file and deploy gateway project again but I want to generate api gateway document automatically.

I've read this repository [MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot](https://github.com/Burgyn/MMLib.SwaggerForOcelot) but I think there should be a another better way.

I'm using .net core 3.1 and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.4.1.

Comment: what's the problem exactly? when you have to deploy a service it infers that you have added new feature, therfore your api docs need to be updated.

Comment: I want to generate api gateway document automatically

Comment: Considering your swagger.json will contain documentation of all 11 micro-services. Can you share the process to generate this combined json file?

Comment: @SaadKhan actually I concatinate all microservices swagger.json(routes and schema) which means it's not generated automatically